# Appending array to a larger one and then returning it

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is to create a function that takes as input a CSV file. From that CSV file I want it to create an array where the data in the first column is the x-coordinate and the data in the second column is the y-coordinate. For every row in the data file I want it to add the data into the array.

```
import numpy as np 

doc = open("d.csv")
headers = doc.readline()


def generateArray(doc):

    for theData in doc: 
        editDocument = theData.strip().split(",")
        x = splitDocument[0]
        y = splitDocument[1]
        createArray = np.array((x, y))
    return createArray 


print(generateArray(doc))
```

When I return it, it simply returns the last row of the CSV file, when in fact I want all arrays created to return. Functions I have used like .append() give me an error saying that "append cannot be used on a 0 dimensional array." Any suggestions on how I can edit my code to give return arrays.

Comment: Collect values in a list, and make array from that.

Answer (score 0):

As a fast (in terms of changing your code) solution, use a generator:

```
def generateArray(doc):
    for theData in doc: 
        editDocument = theData.strip().split(",")
        x = splitDocument[0]
        y = splitDocument[1]
        createArray = [x, y]
        yield createArray

arr = np.array(list(generateArray(doc)))
print(arr)
```

As a better solution, I would suggest that you check how to use [np.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).